# Iterate Through Array in Bash; Exit if No Matches are Found

Tags: bash

In the following function, I can iterate through an array and, if a match is found, break out of the loop and continue with the rest of the program (as intended).

I'd like, though, for the function to exit the rest of the program if exactly no matches are found. How can I achieve that? (I can't have it exit the first time a match is not found, and placing an `exit 1` at the end of the loop doesn't do what I intend).

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but what?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# Array 
MATLAB_VERSION=(
    MATLAB9.4.app
    MATLAB9.3.app
    MATLAB9.2.app
    MATLAB9.1.app
    MATLAB9.0.app
    MATLAB8.6.app
    MATLAB8.5.app
    MATLAB8.3.app 
    MATLAB8.0.app 
    MATLAB7.5.app 
    MATLAB.app 
)

matlab_check() { 
    # is MATLAB*.*.app installed in /Applications?  
    # iterate through array & tell me what you find 

    for MATLAB in "${MATLAB_VERSION[@]}"; 
    do  
        if [ -d "/Applications/$MATLAB" ]; then 
            printf "%s\\n" "FOUND $MATLAB IN /Applications, CONTINUING..."
            break 
        else 
            printf "%s\\n" "SEARCHING for $MATLAB in /Applications..." 
        fi 
    done 
} 

matlab_check
```

Comment: you could set a variable like `found=0` before the loop.  if you do find a matlab version installed, then set `found=1`, then after your loop test it: `(( $found == 0)) && exit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return` from the whole function immediately when you find a match. That way, you can have a "tail part" after the loop, that only runs if no matches were found. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
# You might not care for this declaration of the array contents,
# but it does the same thing, and keeps my example nice and short
MATLAB_VERSION=( MATLAB{9.{4..0},8.{6,5,3,0},{7.5,}}.app )

# RC 0 = found
# RC 1 = not found
matlab_check() {
    for MATLAB in "${MATLAB_VERSION[@]}"; do
        if [ -d "/Applications/${MATLAB}" ]; then
            echo "Found in ${MATLAB}"
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}

matlab_check
echo rc is $?
```

And if you didn't want to be outputting details of where found, the `if..fi`  portion could be reduced down to just this.  No need to use `return 0` because at this point we know that $? must be 0, hence just `return` with no arguments.

```
[ -d "/Applications/${MATLAB}" ] && return
```

Comment: Ah, that's more like it. I'll test a bit later and follow-up thereafter.

Comment: I'm marking the revised answer as correct. Placing the "tail" portion outside of the loop is correct. Thanks.